# ¿Cómo generar un submit de diferente color, tamaño o texto?

Tags: html, html5

```
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset">
```

Amaría poder modificar el estilo de estas dos funciones para poder generar un botón verde grande que diga "votar" y que siga cumpliendo con la función del *submit*, sin alterar nada más.

Usando HTML.

Comment: Bienvenido, de qué funciones hablas? Mira cómo crear un [example].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: <input type="submit">
                <input type="reset"> quisiera poder modificar los botones para hacerlos mas esteticos

Comment: CSS es el lenguaje diseñado para realizar lo que buscas. Si bien podrías hacerlo con HTML, la idea es separar el estilo (la presentación visual) de la estructura de la página. Mi recomendación es que utilices CSS.

Comment: Usa Boostrasp. Te vas a sorprender

Answer (score 1):

Para los estilos ocupas CSS Y para agregar un texto debes usar el atributo `value` de esos `input`

Los estilos pueden ir en un archivo separado, comúnmente con extensión .css

```css
.botonVerde{
  padding:40px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.botonRojo{
  padding:40px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="VOTAR" class="botonVerde" >
<input type="reset" value="RESET" class="botonRojo" >
```

O se pueden escribir dentro del Elemento usando el atributo `style`, a esto se denomina `inline`. Esta forma no se recomienda mucho, principalmente porque a futuro la modificación es un lio. Pero hay veces que no queda otra alternativa que usarlo

```html
<input type="submit" value="VOTAR" style="padding:40px; background-color: green; color: white;" >
<input type="reset" value="RESET" style="padding:40px;background-color: red;color: white;" >
```

Ahora en HTML puro y duro, hasta donde yo entiendo no es posible, y solo lo sería para el casos de las tablas.

Para esto se usan artes arcanas no recomendadas en los estándares modernos

```html
<table bgcolor="red" color="white">
 <tr><td><font color="white">Soy Rojo</font></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dado que el AP pide las cosas en HTML (supongo que puro HTML) sugiero que agregues a tu respuesta algún argumento de por qué es mejor utilizar CSS para esta tarea. Igual ya te dí el +1, pero creo que vale la pena la aclaración. Un saludo.

Comment: Pero con HTML puro, como le va a cambiar el estilo a algo??? Debe usar si o si CSS...

Comment: @OCHOA no, también se puede desde HTML.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev puede darme un ejemplo de ello.

Comment: @OCHOA Aquí tiene: https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/NWEKBVe.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no se, es que si nos ponemos cuadrados, esas son propiedades de estilos, se que dirán que usar CSS viene de archivos externos pero la misma etiqueta **style** tanto en línea como en el head vienen a ser estilos. La verdad creo que confundí cuando se decía **HTML Puro**.